# Windows doesn't failover between internal DNS

Tags: windows, active-directory, internal-dns, failover

We have an Active directory environment with 2 servers - WS2019 being the "main" one holding all FSMO and WS2022 being "reserve", almost all clients are Windows 10. Both are in the same subnet with clients but located in different building (still in same L2, no tunnels or smth). Addresses of both DNS are distributed through MikroTik DHCP - WS2019 192.168.240.100 as primary, WS2022 192.168.240.102 as secondary, both correctly shown in adapter status on every client. Internal DPS are setup to redirect external queries to 8.8.8.8. We can ping both DNS servers fine from all machines.

Recently we had a network maintenance, during which our WS2022 was disconnected from the rest of network (which was still functional). We expected that nothing special would happen, as we still have our WS2019 fully functional and connected to functional network segment. However, this was not the case. We issued name resolve problems on all our Windows clients. Both servers did replication fine, dcdiag /q shows no errors, also no errors in logs.

The fun thing is - if we remove WS2022 from DHCP DNS list and leave only WS2019, it works perfectly fine and resolves everything well. Also weird for me, that this is set as primary DNS and not used.

The question is - what can we check/do to make our clients do a correct failover between the two DNS servers?

Comment: `this is set as primary DNS and not used.` That isn't a failover issue. That's a DNS server that isn't working.

Comment: @GregAskew yes but as I stated in question, if this server is used as only DNS server (secondary not delivered through DHCP), then all is working fine. So I doubt it isn't working completely...

Comment: Current versions of Windows 10 query name servers in parallel. If all the clients are failing when one DNS server is offline, that's a clue that the other server was not "serving".

Comment: @GregAskew this is how it works when I deliver both DNS through DHCP (we use 30s lease time for now, to make changes fast). It looks like WS2019 server is down. However, if I deliver only WS2019 server in DNS list, when leases renew, it suddenly works perfect. Also if I do PS "Resolve-DnsName <any name> -server <WS2019 fqdn>" this also works perfectly fine. So can you please explain what is not exactly working then?

Comment: Regardless of DHCP or not, should only take a few minutes to perform a Netmon packet capture to confirm what is occurring.

Comment: While you've confirmed you can ping both servers, have you checked you can get a DNS reply from the affected clients? Eg, run :
`nslookup amazon.com 192.168.240.100`
do you get a valid responce from the 2019 server, or does it only work if you change that query to point to the 2022 server on .240.102?

Comment: @KeithLangmead yes I can have a DNS reply from both servers, so nslookup amazon.com 192.168.240.10(0/2) produces equal results when both servers are running. However, now I'm not sure about nslookup responce while WS22 is down, might gonna check that.